# dynamically add Two floors components react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a JSON file called `example.json`, which looks like this:

```
{"key:"k1" ,"children":[{"key:"k1" ,"type":"View "},{"key:"k1" ,"type":"Text "}]}
```

I want to add component to this JSON dynamically, and I've tried the following:

```
import Json from 'example.json'
this.state={json:[]}; in constrcutor(props);

this.setState({json:son}) in componentDidMount();

render() {
    return(
    this.state.json.map(
       (item,index) => { 
          return <View> {this.getChildView(index)} </View>
       });
    )
}


getChildView(index){
    this.state.json[index].map((item)={
         if(item.type==='Text){
                 return <Text>{...}</View>
         }
    })
}
```

However, in step #4, `childView` is not displayed. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: i find that replace code in getChildView with getChildView() in render will work. really strange

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it helps :

```
import Json from 'example.json'
    this.state={json:[]}; in constrcutor(props);

    this.setState({json:son}) in componentDidMount();

   render(){
        return(
        this.state.json.map(
           (item,index)=>{ 
              return <View >{this.getChildView(index)} </View>});
        )}


   getChildView = (index) =>{
        this.state.json[index].map((item)={
             if(item.type==='Text){
                     return <Text>{...}</View>
             }
         }
        )
    }
```